# How to automatically mount dmg when usb is mounted

Tags: macos, usb, mount, automount

I'm developing an app and this app is package only for mac on dmg format.

This app will be distributed through usb storage. What I'm looking for is the process to, as soon as the usb storage is mounted, the dmg file is also mounted and allow the user to copy the .app to application. I don't want the user to go on the usb, double-click on the dmg to mount it.

Windows is doing it through autorun.inf

```
[autorun] 
open=setup.exe 
icon=setup.exe,0
label=My install CD
```

Any idea on how mac works ?

Regards

Comment: Thanks but this one is linked to automount dmg at login. In my case, any scripts must be done and stored on the usb stick as if I give the usb to someone, once usb plugged in, it automout the dmg file

Comment: Instead of supplying a dmg file, you could create a Mac HFS file system as another (or only) partition on the USB device.